# JOIN ON with AND clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm having a hard time with a JOIN QUERY and it could be from my difficulty to grasp the JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.Column1 = TABLE_A.Column1 
             AND (TABLE_B.Column1 + CONVERT(varchar(10), TABLE_B.Column2)) != TABLE_A.Column1
```

I need to obtain rows from both table where both those conditions are met but currently the returned results are as if the AND condition wasn't even present...

Any idea on the achieve this? To help put in context:

```
Table A         Table B
ABCD            ABCD        21          Username1
ABCD21          ABCD        10          Username2
ABCD                        
ABCD            
ABCD21
ABCD21
```

Desired output:

```
Table C
ABCD        10      Username1
ABCD        10      Username1
ABCD        10      Username1
```

P.S. I currently can do the opposite of my question which is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
JOIN TABLE_B ON (TABLE_B.Column1 + CONVERT(varchar(10), TABLE_B.Column2)) = TABLE_A.Column1
```

Comment: Question is not clear.   That is not even the opposite.  It would be Username1 in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AND is evaluated
If the first condition is true then the second is guaranted to be true unless TABLE_B.Column2 is null or empty

if "one" = "one"
then "one" + "two" != "one"

```
ON   TABLE_B.Column1                                           = TABLE_A.Column1 
AND (TABLE_B.Column1 + CONVERT(varchar(10), TABLE_B.Column2)) != TABLE_A.Column1
```

Each row is evaluated on its own

Please better describe what you are trying to do

This may be what you want

```
SELECT B1.*
FROM TABLE_A A 
JOIN TABLE_B B1
      ON B1.Column1 = A.Column1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B2
      on (B2.Column1 + CONVERT(varchar(10), B2.Column2)) = A.Column1
WHERE B2.Column1 IS NULL;
```

try

```
on (B2.Column1 + CONVERT(varchar(10), B2.Column2)) != A.Column1
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. Your explanation makes sense and my logic was flawed! 
You can look at the tables in my post and the desired output for what I try to achieve. I will try you query and see what comes out of it.

Comment: Doesn't work, output:  
  
`ABCD        10      Username1`  
`ABCD        10      Username1`  
`ABCD        10      Username1`  
`ABCD        21      Username2`  
`ABCD        21      Username2`  
`ABCD        21      Username2`

Comment: Don't know what to say.  If on (B2.Column1 + CONVERT(varchar(10), B2.Column2)) = A.Column1 is the opposite of what you want then it should work.

Comment: Tried the update beforehand and it returns nothing. The first join is the problem because for each ABCD value in A, there's a match in B on each row as well. Therefore the return output table is only containing ABCD with matching columns from B. So the second wont do much since the condition is always false.

Comment: Well some ideas for you to work with.  I will delete once you have and accepted answer.

Comment: It's good! Added this at the end of your suggestion: `AND B1.Column3 NOT LIKE (
SELECT Top 1 TABLE_B.Column3
FROM TABLE_A
JOIN TABLE_B 
ON (TABLE_B.Column1 + CONVERT(varchar(10), TABLE_B.Column2)) = TABLE_A.Column1)` So basically get all the results except if it matches the "results" from this other query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are multiple rows that match the first condition.  Some also satisfy the second condition.

I think you are looking for a `left join` with a `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A a LEFT JOIN
     TABLE_B b
     ON b.Column1 = a.Column1 AND
        (b.Column1 + CONVERT(varchar(10), b.Column2)) = a.Column1
WHERE b.Column1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Followed that lead previously without success. I tried your query but that didn't work; it returns all the table A rows, adding all columns from table B with null values.